# File Not Found exception thrown when the file is there?

Tags: android

I can see the image file there? so why is it thrown an exception, I have trebled checked, tried different images and folders but no luck they all throw an file not found exception.

Any info welcome please.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/127437025-picsay.jpg");
```

Comment: Try `getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` then append your filename.

Comment: Thx MisterSquonk for your answer, no luck though:( Can you tell me the path to get a drawable image so I can test one of them? many thx

Comment: @user1136994 so when you say the file is there, are you really sure then? Compare the file path you are using with the real.

Answer (score 0):

It will sure work as it work for me

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
```

android do not  forget to mention permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thx guys double and treble checked everything, no luck, vsn someone show me  the exact path to my drawable folder? If the sdcard is busy can I still access it?

Comment: it work buddy for me.You are giving some wrong path.And what do you mean by busy sdcard?

Comment: I change the image to bg.jpg so I can't go wrong with a typo, have placed the image directly after sdcard main folder, so its sdcard/bg.jpg, its says file not found /sdcard/bg.jpg. my phone says sdcard busy trying to access the sdcard when plugged in to laptop and debug on eclipse. What's the path to drawable folder please?

Comment: I have not face such strange problem ever..change accees to memory card in android

Comment: I now have 5 upload image to remote server classes  all full of problems, I got one working but the ends up a application/octet file I can't do  nothing with, close to giving up on this app.

Comment: i did not understand what exactly you want.First you were saying that you are accessing file from sdcard and getting file not found exception.Now uploading to server.If you have two problem then ask two question.And yes donot give up.Keep on try

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions in your androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simone.wk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```